# Finding binary tree height in Assembly (MIPS)

Tags: assembly, recursion, height, binary-tree, mips

Ok, so I'm trying to calculate the height of a binary tree recursively in Assembly, but I'm struggling to get the right number. My code right now explores the tree and does nothing more, because the only thing I got out of it was to count the number of left and right leaves. Could someone help me with this? Is my code completely wrong or do I only need to add some lines to calculate the height? Any help is appreciated.

p.s.: Don't mind the comments, they are in italian

**EDIT: Kind of improved code with english comments**

```
.data
radice:.word 17, node1, node2
node1:.word 5, node3, 0
node2:.word 8, node4, node5
node3:.word 1, node6, node7
node4:.word 2, 0, 0
node5:.word 3, 0, node8
node6:.word 5, 0, 0
node7:.word 12, 0, node9
node8:.word 6, 0, 0
node9:.word 2, 0, 0

.text
main:
la $s0, radice #first node
jal recursive

recursive:
addi $sp, $sp, -8 #making space in the stack
sw $ra, 0($sp) #save ra
beqz $s0, null #Does this node exist?
sw $s0, 4($sp) #If it does, save it in the stack
lw $s1, 0($s0) ####Display wich node is currently being examined#####
li $t9, 0  #Control
li $a3, 0  #Left height
li $a2, 0  #Right height
j left  #Examine left child of this node


null:
beq $t9, 1, nullL  #If this control is set to 1, this was a left child
li $a2, 0  #Right height is 0
lw $ra, 0($sp)  #load ra from stack
addi $sp, $sp, 8  #clear stack
jr $ra #jump to ra
nullL:
li $a3, 0  #Left height is 0
la $s0, 4($sp) #load father address from stack
lw $s2, 0($s0) ####Display who is the father####
lw $ra, 0($sp) #load ra
addi $sp, $sp, 8 #clear stack
jr $ra #jump to ra


left:
li $t9, 1 #set control to 1
lw $s0, 4($s0) #load left child of this node
jal recursive #start recursion
right:
lw $s0, 8($s0) #load right child of this node
jal recursive # start recursion
j right #Don't know if this will be useful
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all, where is the "recursive" tag? can't see it.
also, why are u increasing the height only for the right children and not for the left ones?

Comment: The recursive tag is just under this line: 



`sw $t1, 8($sp) #Salva il figlio destro`

The fact that I'm increasing the height for the right children is an error, right now my code is supposed to explore the tree and nothing more. I'll edit the original code to remove that line.

Comment: shouldnt you use lw instead of la (first line after "continue")? the following address is stored as a word, isn't it? sorry its very hard to understand your code w/ italian comments

Comment: I've edited the original post with what I think is an improved version of my code (with english comments this time). Now whenever it gets to a node with no children it enters a loop instead of retrieving the previous node and exploring his right child